# Looping through dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have 5 dataframes A through E and I'd like to apply the same process to all frames. I've executed a loop but it doesn't overwrite the original dataframes I'd like to change, they result as identical to the frames I've fed to the loop:

```
frames = [A,B,C,D,E]

for df in frames:
    df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Unnamed')))] # Drop columns with "Unnamed" in column name
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper()) # Convert columns to caps
    df['Unique Name'] = df['Name'] + ' ' + df['Gender'] + ' ' + df['Classification'] + ' ' + df['Silhouette']
```

The exact same code works if I run it individually for each dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:

```
frames = [A,B,C,D,E]
def update(df):
       df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Unnamed')))] # Drop columns with "Unnamed" in column name
       df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper()) # Convert columns to caps
       df['Unique Name'] = df['Name'] + ' ' + df['Gender'] + ' ' + df['Classification'] + ' ' + df['Silhouette']
       return df
for i in frames:
  i = update(i)
```

The issue with your code is you are just overwrite `df`, instead of updating your actual Dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `frames[i]` inside the loop instead of `df`:

```py
for i in range(len(frames)):
  frames[i] = frames[i][frames[i].columns. ...
  ...
```

Thus you overwrite the data frames inside the list. An easy adaptation of your code:

```
for i, df in zip(range(len(frames)), frames):
  df = df[df.columns.drop(list(df.filter(regex='Unnamed')))] # Drop columns with "Unnamed" in column name
  df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper()) # Convert columns to caps
  df['Unique Name'] = df['Name'] + ' ' + df['Gender'] + ' ' + df['Classification'] + ' ' + df['Silhouette']

  frames[i] = df
```